# Movie from 80s-90s with humans trapped on alien ship while duplicated on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-abduction, mind-uploading

I am trying to find a movie I watched when I was a kid. There are a small group of humans that don't know each other waking up in a cell on an alien ship. I think they are actually duplicates on the ship which are constructed to hold the humans minds while aliens are controlling their actual bodies on Earth in order to scout out Earth. In the case of one female character, the aliens have sensory experiences like eating (that is one of the first scenes of the movie, I think). The aliens' bodies are in glass tubes or tanks and the humans have to kill them, which they know how to do because of a sympathetic alien (the female one at the start).

Comment: I know this one, it is currently on either or both Netflix and Amazon Prime.

Answer (score 5):

Lets try this

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146403/

"The Advanced Guard (1998)" aka "The Colony" 1998 (Currently available on Amazon Prime for streaming)

Lead Female Alien is scouting the Earth for the Fleet. Reports back. The lead female alien returns with 3 additional aliens.

Seems the lead female enjoys the sensations she experiences from being in a human body .... no need to provide spoilers this is probably the movie.

Low budget "B" type movie.

I am adding this:
"As a prelude to full-blown alien invasion, a team of four aliens telepathically linked with their lifelike human-looking android bodies abducts four random humans to test them to determine if humans can make good slaves."